# How to disable click listener on image view android

Tags: android, image, imageview, onclicklistener

I am working on android application in which i am making click listener on image view. I just want to disable image listener, for example i have a edit button , without clicking edit button image view listener should be disabled.

```
image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clickCount == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enabled",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    fName.setEnabled(true);
                    lName.setEnabled(true);
                    mailText.setEnabled(true);
                    mobileText.setEnabled(true);
                    mCond.setEnabled(true);
                    mNotes.setEnabled(true);
                    medication.setEnabled(true);
                    alReact.setEnabled(true);
                    dofo.setEnabled(true);
                    image.setEnabled(true);
                    editText.setText("Done");
                    clickCount = 1;

                }

                else if (clickCount == 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    fName.setEnabled(false);
                    lName.setEnabled(false);
                    mailText.setEnabled(false);
                    mobileText.setEnabled(false);
                    meond.setEnabled(false);
                    mNotes.setEnabled(false);
                    meation.setEnabled(false);
                    alReact.setEnabled(false);
                    doInfo.setEnabled(false);
                    image.setEnabled(false);
                    editText.setText("Edit");
                    updatingUser();
                    clickCount = 0;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

just add it in onCreate Method

`image.setEnabled(false);`

Comment: If you press a lot of buttons at the same time and you want to disable the other buttons on the first click, then it seems this method is not fast enough, Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 7):

Use this line into your XML:

```
android:clickable="false"
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want To clear the onClick-listenener of the imageView. Simply call

```
myImageView.setOnClickListener(null);
```

Hope it helps.

Update: "Advantage" (depends on what you want") of setOnClickListener to null is that it will not change the background of the button like it does at setClickable(false) or setEnabled(false).

Because the button wants to show the user if he is in an enabled(false) or setClickable(false) mode.

If you don't want that, simply use my answere. :) hope it helps and gives a direction of what you want

Answer (score 5):

Try This:

```
image.setClickable(false);
```

Comment: You have to ensure that the setClickable of an element is defined after setting the lister of that element

Answer (score 3):

Use  **image.setClickable(false)** to set imageview clickable disable
try this

```
 image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
 image.setClickable(false);

 editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

  image.setClickable(true);
  }
```

Hope this will help you friend :)