# How can make other button disable when one is clicked android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, logic

I have a scenario where I have 5 ImageView and when one ImageView is clicked i want to set other 4 ImageView as Disabled. Please help to get logic for that.
My Logic for this : when 1 image is click set other 4 imageView as disable but imageView.setClickable(false) is not working.

This Attached Image is a dialog box that appears when users wants to edit something from recycler view. Recycler view contains data like : "Amount", "Item name", "Price", "Expense Type" and expense type image is set to On corresponding to "Expense Type".

I am stuck in this moment. Please help me out to solve this.

I have attached my scenario images Please check it out.
[image]

> > Here's my code for this

```
public class MyAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ExpenseModel, MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    private int lastPosition = -1;
    private String whichCategorySelected = "";
    private int calImgClick = 0;
    private int groceryClick = 0;
    private int bikeClick = 0;
    private int rentClick = 0;
    private int foodsClick = 0;
    private int beerClick = 0;


    public MyAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ExpenseModel> options, Context context) {
        super(options);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position, @NonNull ExpenseModel model) {
        holder.expenseItem.setText(model.getDescription());
        holder.expenseAmount.setText("Rs. " + model.getAmount());
        holder.expenseDate.setText(model.getTime());
        String expType = model.getExType();
        switch (expType) {
            case "Beer":
                holder.category.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.beer);
                break;
            case "Grocery":
                holder.category.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grocery);
                break;
            case "Bike":
                holder.category.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bike);
                break;
            case "Rent":
                holder.category.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rent);
                break;
            default:
                holder.category.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fd);
                break;
        }


        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showPopMenuOnItemClicked(view, holder.getLayoutPosition(), model.getDescription(), model.getAmount(), model.getTime(), model.getExType());
            }
        });

    }

    private void showPopMenuOnItemClicked(View v, int pos, String getExpTitle, String getExpAmt, String getDate, String whichCatSelected) {
        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, v);
        popupMenu.getMenu().add("Edit");
        popupMenu.getMenu().add("Delete");
        popupMenu.getMenu().add("Delete All");
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                if (menuItem.getTitle().equals("Edit")) {
                    showUpdateDialogBox(v, getExpTitle, getExpAmt, getDate, whichCatSelected);
                } else if (menuItem.getTitle().equals("Delete")) {
                    FirebaseReference.expenseReference(context)
                            .child(String.valueOf(getRef(pos).getKey()))
                            .removeValue()
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        Toast.makeText(context, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Delete everything", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        popupMenu.show();
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    private void showUpdateDialogBox(View v, String getExpTitle, String getExpAmt, String getDate, String whichCatSelected) {
        DialogPlus dialog = DialogPlus.newDialog(context)
                .setContentHolder(new ViewHolder(R.layout.update_expense_layout))
                .setExpanded(false)
                .setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogPlus dialog) {
                        onDismissSetClickCountToZero();
                        Utility.hideKeyboard(context, v);
                    }
                })
                .create();

        View myView = dialog.getHolderView();
        TextView update_expense_date = myView.findViewById(R.id.update_expense_date);
        EditText update_expense_title = myView.findViewById(R.id.update_expense_title);
        EditText update_expense_amount = myView.findViewById(R.id.update_expense_amount);
        ImageView update_calendarImg = myView.findViewById(R.id.update_calendar);
        Button update_button = myView.findViewById(R.id.update_btn);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = myView.findViewById(R.id.update_linearCalenderLayout);
        linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        CalendarView calendarView = myView.findViewById(R.id.update_calenderView);
        LinearLayout categoryLayout = myView.findViewById(R.id.update_categoryIconsLayout);
        TextView categoryTextView = myView.findViewById(R.id.update_selectCategory_heading);

        update_expense_title.setText(getExpTitle);
        update_expense_amount.setText(getExpAmt);
        update_expense_date.setText(getDate);

        ImageView beer = myView.findViewById(R.id.update_beer);
        ImageView bike = myView.findViewById(R.id.update_bike);
        ImageView grocery = myView.findViewById(R.id.update_grocery);
        ImageView foods = myView.findViewById(R.id.update_foods);
        ImageView rent = myView.findViewById(R.id.update_rent);

        TextView desc_grocery = myView.findViewById(R.id.update_desc_grocery);
        TextView desc_bike = myView.findViewById(R.id.update_desc_bike);
        TextView desc_beer = myView.findViewById(R.id.update_desc_beer);
        TextView desc_foods = myView.findViewById(R.id.update_desc_foods);
        TextView desc_rent = myView.findViewById(R.id.update_desc_rent);

        setIconVisible(whichCatSelected, bike, grocery, foods, beer, rent,
                desc_bike, desc_grocery, desc_foods, desc_beer, desc_rent);
        setWhichCategorySelected(whichCatSelected);



        Toast.makeText(context, "Default select = " + getWhichCategorySelected() + "  click = " + rentClick, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        update_calendarImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                calImgClick++;
                if (calImgClick >= 2) {
                    linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    categoryLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    categoryTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    calImgClick = 0;
                } else {
                    linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    categoryLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    categoryTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

            }
        });
        rent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (getWhichCategorySelected().equals("") || getWhichCategorySelected().equals("Rent")){
                    rentClick ++;
                    if (rentClick >= 2) {
                        setWhichCategorySelected("");
                        rent.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rent_off);
                        desc_rent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        grocery.setClickable(true);
                        bike.setClickable(true);
                        foods.setClickable(true);
                        beer.setClickable(true);
                        rentClick = 0;
                    } else {
                        setWhichCategorySelected("Rent");
                        rent.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rent);
                        desc_rent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        grocery.setClickable(false);
                        bike.setClickable(false);
                        foods.setClickable(false);
                        beer.setClickable(false);
                    }
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Category is selected " + getWhichCategorySelected(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                Toast.makeText(context, "whichCategorySelected = " + getWhichCategorySelected(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        grocery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (getWhichCategorySelected().equals("") || getWhichCategorySelected().equals("Grocery")){
                    groceryClick ++;
                    if (groceryClick >= 2) {
                        setWhichCategorySelected("");
                        grocery.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grocery_off);
                        desc_grocery.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        rent.setClickable(true);
                        bike.setClickable(true);
                        foods.setClickable(true);
                        beer.setClickable(true);
                        rentClick = 0;
                    } else {
                        setWhichCategorySelected("Grocery");
                        grocery.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grocery);
                        desc_grocery.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        rent.setClickable(false);
                        bike.setClickable(false);
                        foods.setClickable(false);
                        beer.setClickable(false);
                    }
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Category is selected " + getWhichCategorySelected(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                Toast.makeText(context, "whichCategorySelected = " + getWhichCategorySelected(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        update_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                updateChildren(update_expense_amount, update_expense_title, update_expense_date, whichCatSelected);
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }
    
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView expenseItem, expenseAmount, expenseDate;
        ImageView category;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            expenseItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerItemView);
            expenseAmount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerAmountView);
            expenseDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerDateView);
            category = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerCategory);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27200007/how-to-disable-click-listener-on-image-view-android     and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-enable-disable-click-listener-on-views-in-android/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27200007/how-to-disable-click-listener-on-image-view-android

This is not working for me.

Comment: Try replacing imageview with imagebutton...if this doesn't work ..will provide u with another soln...